# SQL: ячейка должна принять значение следующей НЕпустой ячейки

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть таблица с id такси, временем и их статусом (статус = 1, когда такси едет, и 0, когда стоит). В текущем столбце статус указана только СМЕНА состояния машины, поэтому если машина сохраняет свое состояние, то ячейка is Null.

Также важно учитывать id машины, чтобы машина под 1 номером не получила статус 2 машины.

Какой требуется запрос, чтобы получить значение, как в скриншоте в зеленом столбце?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой тогда смысл выбирать строки, где состояние не меняется? Выкиньте их просто

Comment: По заданию мне нужно сохранить все строки

Comment: В следующий раз постарайтесь давать пример данных в виде текста, желательно прямо в виде create table и insert. Мне пришлось потратить целых 5 минут на создание тестовой таблицы, при том что на написание и тестирование запроса ушло секунд 30.

Comment: Спасибо за совет! В следующий раз буду давать код с тестовой таблицей

Answer (score 1):

Используя оконные функции сначала разобьем выборку на группы состоящие из записи содержащей нужный статус и предшествующих ей записей с статусом null. Для этого удобно использовать функцию `count(x)` так как она считает количество НЕ NULL значений и следовательно увеличивается единицу на любом НЕ NULL значении. Применяем ее с разбивкой на id и обратным порядком сортировки по времени.

После получения номеров групп мы можем брать максимальное значение статуса внутри одной такой группы для всех строк этой группы.

```
select *, max(status) over(partition by id, grp) result
  from (
    select *,
           count(status) over(partition by id order by ts desc) grp
      from test
  ) x
 order by id, ts
```

Comment: Спасибо! Почти получилось. 

Последние три null так и остались null-ми

Comment: @Else А почему последние три null должны быть именно 0, а не чем то другим ? Если это константное значение, то просто приведите null к 0, как это обычно делается с помощью `coalesce(max(val) over(partition by id, grp), 0)`